# A reliable source of ambient temperature and wind speed dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, pvlib

I am calculating the energy yield of a solar PV system using PVlib python. For radiation, I am using the clear-sky method (because I have some assumptions in my project). I am looking for a reliable source for wind speed and ambient temperature datasets so that I can calculate cell/module temperature using Sandia and PVsyst models I need data for the whole year at a 10min resolution.

Is it possible through PVGIS? If yes, how?

Any suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: I don't know how accurate the data is, but you can retrieve this type of data from [NASA Power](https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?)

Comment: @Nikhil, many weather datasets cover only part of the world, so you might edit the question to include the location of interest.  One option for you may be NREL's PSM3 dataset, which includes 5-minute temperature and wind speed.  pvlib has a function to retrieve PSM3 data.

Comment: @Nikhil, the NASA site, provides data for the entire world based on lat and lon position.  The information is derived from satellite information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Solcast historical time series data for one location for free. Check [Solcast Data Samples](https://solcast.com/historical-and-tmy/data-samples/). There are several time series climate data available (including solar radiation estimations) with global coverage